# having an NSDictionary that is always stored in an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to have a "permanent" NSDictionary in my app, in which from the beginning of the app launch, I can get access to the elements and even after I kill the app and start it again.
This NSDictionary needs to be stored tightly with the app. One way would be to just to create the NSDictionary from a Web Service data every time the app launches, then create a singleton class that would represent this NSDictionary, but I don't think this is good.

The NSDictionary will approximately hold 10-20 objects, where the key would be a NSString or NSDate and the value would be a NSArray. The NSArray would have a maximum of approximately 50 entries in it (on average probably there will only be 5-25 entries).

I am planning to use this NSDictionary as a part of a calculation that I am doing inside the delegate `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` each time a user moves every 50-100 meters.

Suggestions are appreciated on the best way I could do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just having the NSDictionary in a singleton will not keep it between app launches, you'll need to save it to disk, and then read it from the disk when the app starts.

If you have no custom objects (subclasses you've created) in the NSDictionary, or in the NSArrays or non at all, you can use this method to save the NSDictionary is:

[`- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a)

and to open the dictionary from disk:

[`- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithContentsOfFile%3a)

---

However if you do have custom objects they will need to conform to the NSCoding protocol. And you'll have to use 2 different methods to save and open it:

NSCoding is a protocol, so in your header you need to add it on the end of the interface line:

```
@interface myClassName : NSObject <NSCoding> {
```

(where the only thing you should add is [`<NSCoding>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html))

Then in your implementation of your subclass, you need to add the following methods:

[`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder%3a)

and:

[`- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/encodeWithCoder%3a)

The `initWithCoder:` method gets called when you want to unarchive(/open) your NSDictionary (which somewhere contains this class)

`encodeWithCoder:` is what gets called when your NSDictionary is archived(/saved).
You don't call either of these yourself. You need to add code in them:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])) {
        aProperty = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"aProperty"] retain];
        anotherProperty = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"anotherProperty"] retain];
        aFloat = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:@"aFloat"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:aProperty forKey:@"aProperty"];
    [encoder encodeObject:anotherProperty forKey:@"anotherProperty"];
    [encoder encodeFloat:aFloat forKey:@"aFloat"];
}
```

You need to have similar lines for each value you want to store (generally all the properties, [and instance variables] your class has). Note the how the `float` line is different to the others.

The keys can be any string you want, as long each property has it's own unique key and that they match between the two methods. I personally use the name of the property as it's just easier to understand.

when you actually want to save your NSDictionary you use:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myDictionary toFile:pathToMyDictionary];
```

and to open the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:pathToMyDictionary];
```

(depending on your code you may need to `retain` `myDictionary`)

---

To get the path to your dictionary (for both saving and opening) do:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathToMyDictionary = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDictionary.dat"];
```

Hope that helps, if you have any more questions about this answer, just comment :)

Comment: what is the NSCoding protocol?

Comment: NSCoding protocol requires two methods, one that encodes the properties of the class, and the other decodes the properties. I will edit my answer.

Comment: one question.. you have pathToMyDictionary.. where should this path be, for example?

Comment: You need to get the path to the app's documents directory (search stackoverflow for how to) and then append a file name (eg "mydict.dat", the extension can be anything)

Comment: After a search, I found that I need to use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); which returns an NSArray.. so I just pick the first path in this NSArray?

Comment: Yes. You should probably check that the arrays count is 1 as well

Comment: And this is done the first time only? Where should we store this path at if we want to later open it?

Comment: You will have to open the file every time the app launches. You can create the path each time you want to open/save the dictionary or you can set the path to an ivar which will allow you to access it throughout the class.

Comment: So after finding a path that I can use to save.. I need to save this path as a String so that I can use later on to open it again?

Comment: Just create the path as you need it. What do you mean path format?

Comment: ok, after getting the path that I got from  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains, I need to specify the filename to store this dictionary into?

Comment: also if I am storing a dictionary with an object of NSArray and each NSArray contains a custom Location class, does this Location class need to conform with NSCoding protocol?

Comment: also what if I have a custom dictionary class that I created, can it be stored?

Comment: so say the object that I want to store is http://friendpaste.com/1Y9hBLn3819YIJDLcZKNbI

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to get the path to the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, the custom `Location` class will need to conform to NSCoding

Comment: You will also need `IntervalDictionary`to conform to NSCoding, you will need to encode/decode the 2 arrays. It would be helpful if you posted a tree (text based) of your setup in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want NSUserDefaults. That stores app preferences but can be used other bits of data as well. It is essentially a dedicated, singleton dictionary that is universally accessible and is automatically saved.

Comment: I don't know... I think NSUserDefaults doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: If your saving application state then it's a legitimate use of the user defaults. Your description of your needs makes it sound like something that the defaults are used for.

Comment: if I shut down the app and I want to load it back again, will it store the NSDictionary in the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Yes, everything written to NSUserDefaults is saved immediately upon writing and is available immediately upon app start.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily generate an NSDictionary from a plist file using `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:foo]`

If appropriate, the plist could be included in your app bundle, or you could grab the data from a web service on first launch and write it out to a plist that the dictionary is loaded from in the future.

Comment: well, I'll also need to write to this NSDictionary