# using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am fairly new to archiving an object I have. I have a dictionary that I want to archive.. so first I got the path by doing:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        dictionaryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

so is the next step to append this dictionaryPath with a .txt? Or should I create something first at this directory? What is then the data type?

I want to be able to use it for:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:locationDic toFile:dictionaryPath];
```

Where dictionaryPath is the path to store this NSDictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains will give you an array of directory paths. So if you take the first one, you need to append a filename (whatever filename you'd like, with whatever extension you'd like), and then use that path as the location to write out to.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *dictionaryFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Filename.extension"];
 [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:locationDic toFile:dictionaryFilePath];
```

Comment: does that filename has to exist first before? or will it create it automatically if it's not there?

Comment: well.. I did that and actually no file is created at the folder Document

Comment: @EquinoX - You can check to make sure the path is what you expect it to be by adding: NSLog(@"dictionaryFilePath: %@", dictionaryFilePath); Does the console show the path you expect?

Comment: I actually can see the file created now.. is it true that if I want to store a custom class that I created then I should add a NSCoding protocol to it? I am creating my own custom dictionary class that stores a Location object

Comment: here's a sample class of what I will actually be storing in the file http://friendpaste.com/1Y9hBLn3819YIJDLcZKNbI

Comment: Any custom classes that are being written to disk through the call to the NSKeyedArchiver should implement -encodeWithCoder and -initWithCoder.

Comment: in this case I am creating a custom dictionary, in which it has a custom key and custom object stored in it.. so which one should implement those two methods? Is it just the dictionary or this rule propagates down?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to subclass NSDictionary. But if you really need to, your dictionary subclass should implement the coder methods as well. Everything in your object graph that's being serialized to disk needs to implement the coder methods. It propagates from the root.

Comment: you can read the background behind this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445672/having-an-nsdictionary-that-is-always-stored-in-an-app