# SQLite insert works in simulator but not on device

Tags: xcode, sqlite, ios5

Here is  SQLite code which I call and pass one variable. Where is problem?

```
-(IBAction)insertPet:(NSString *) name{

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into pet (name) values ('%@');", name];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

NSLog(@"1 - %@",query);

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSLog(@"2 - %@",query);

    if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(statement)){

        NSLog(@"Query - %@",query);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
}
```

Comment: NSLog(@"1 - %@",query) and NSLog(@"2 - %@",query) pass throught. Cant reach NSLog(@"Query - %@",query).

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what the error message was...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your database is placed in the application bundle. If that's the case, you will have to create a writable copy of your database to be able to perform queries that change  the database (like INSERT or UPDATE). The most popular way of doing so is to copy the database from the bundle to the Documents folder.

Comment: Sure, use [NSFileManager method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:) for copying. To get your Documents path check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508433/using-nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-properly)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting the app from your device,restart the device,clean the app in Xcode then load it again,also check that Target Membership is selected on the database.